# Inheriting SplitterPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, splitterpanel

I have the following C# class:

```
class BufferedSplitPanel : SplitterPanel
{
    public BufferedSplitPanel()
    {
         this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

But the compiler (and Intellisense) tell me `this` doesn't have such a member `DoubleBuffered` (or any other member for that matter). MSDN clearly states that it does, since it inherits from Panel. If I change the `SplitterPanel` to `Panel` it compiles. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your exact error, you can't inherit from a sealed class.

Comment: Added `winforms` tag because it's related if you think otherwise revert my change. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SplitterPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitterpanel.aspx) is `sealed` class while [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) is not.

You can't derive from `sealed` type.

> [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):
>
> A sealed class cannot be inherited. It is an error to use a sealed class as a base class. Use the sealed modifier in a class declaration to prevent inheritance of the class.

If you want to extend functionality of `sealed` class the best way [IMO] is to create [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). E.g.:

```
public static class SplitterPanelExtensions {
    public static void MyAdvancedMethod(this SplitterPanel splitterPanel) {
        /*
         * Check if splitterPanel is null and throw ArgumentNullException.
         * because extension methods are called via "call" IL instruction.
         */
        //Implementation.
    }

    //Other extension methods...
}
```

Another way is to create class that will be holding instance of sealed class. This one is better choice if you want to hide some part of interface of class you're wrapping. E.g.:

```
public class SplitterPanelWrapper {
    private readonly SplitterPanel m_SplitterPanel;

    public SplitterPanelWrapper(SplitterPanel splitterPanel) {
        m_SplitterPanel = splitterPanel;
    }

    //Other implementation. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any Idea how I can get a double-buffered SplitterPanel?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any DoubleBuffered Property in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitterpanel.aspx). Are you sure you need that property? It doesn't seem to make much sense to use it either.

Apart from that, the MSDN also says that the class is **sealed**. You cannot derive from it. You should be getting compiler errors.

Comment: `I can't see any DoubleBuffered Property in the MSDN documentation` You don't see it because it's defined in `Panel` class and `SplitterPanel` derives from it.

Comment: But you see all other inherited properties there, marked by " (Inherited from Control.)", which I would have expected for DoubleBuffered, too, since it's inherited from control, too. But it isn't there.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitterpanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx I gess it was removed in 4.5, but I am using 4.0

Comment: Ok, I added the .Net 4.0 tag to your question.